# Objects sliding on a frictionless surface

Tags: calculus, physics

An object with the mass 2 kg slides on a frictionless surface. When the velocity of the object is h, the object is subjected to a force (air resistance) that's $5v^2$ N.

Apparently the equation is

$$ F = ma = m\frac{dv}{dt} = -5v^2 $$

I do understand how to solve this differential equation. What I don't understand is why the downwards force is equal to air resistance?

Edit: Forgot to mention that v(0) = 3.

Comment: I think your question is missing some details

Comment: What do we have to calculate?

Comment: Dheeraj: What I don't understand is why the downwards force is equal to air resistance? I copied the question from my textbook (translated to english).

Comment: downward force is not equal to air resistance. that "-" sign in front of F means that it is acting opposite to the motion of the object

Comment: This isn't an integral; it's a differential equation.

Comment: Dheeraj: Yes, opposite directions, but the same magnitude, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The velocity is horizontal.  We might as well call it along the $+x$ axis. The air resistance is opposite the velocity, so is in the $-x$ direction, horizontal. You now have $F=m\frac {dv}{dt}=-5v^2$  The equation separates-can you solve it?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have solved the equation. I just don't understand the logic behind the equation. Do you not have to assume terminal velocity?

Comment: You are just given the equation, so there doesn't have to be any logic behind it.  It is true that air drag increases as the square of the velocity.  Terminal velocity would apply if you had a fixed accelerating force and air drag. It would be the point where the drag equaled the accelerating force.  In this  case we are given a (magical) starting velocity and asked to calculate the deceleration.  Maybe it was a car that was accelerating and at $t=0$ the clutch is depressed, eliminating the drive from the engine.

Comment: Perhaps I should have clarified. I was not given the equation. The problem consists of 2 parts. First part of the problem is to set up the equation based on what they tell us about mass and air resistance. This is where I'm struggling.. Solving the equation is quite simple.

Comment: You haven't provided the information for setting up the equation, so I can't comment on that.  I know that experimentally air resistance being roughly proportional to $v^2$ is correct.  I don't know the theoretical justification for it.  The drag coefficient does change with velocity, but not much at low speeds like this.

Comment: This is the information provided by the textbook: An object with the mass 2 kg slides on a frictionless surface. When the velocity of the object is h, the object is subjected to a force (air resistance) that's $5v^2$ N. We also know that $ v(0)=3 $. Set up a differential equation for the velocity of the object.

Comment: The differential equation is just as I showed, with $2$ substituted in for $m$.  I don't understand what your question is.  Air resistance is a force applied to the object.  It works against the velocity, which is where the minus sign comes from.  Are you still concerned with "downward"?  Maybe you mean "reducing speed" instead of a direction?

Comment: I understand the meaning of the minus sign. What I'm struggling with is the fact that from the equation it follows that the magnitude of $ mg $ equals the magnitude of the air resistance $ 5v^2 $, i.e. the net force on the object is zero. How could I possibly know that the net force equals zero if I don't assume terminal velocity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19670/discussion-between-ross-millikan-and-user1904218).

Comment: Did you forget that the gravitational force is in the $-y$ direction? This $F$ is in the horizontal direction, and has nothing to do with gravity. The object is not falling.

Comment: @Dylan:  I didn't forget.  That was exactly what I was discussing with OP.  It came out in the chat session.

Comment: Of course I was talking to the OP, not you.